# Is require_once "../../file/config.php" the most secure way to hide my config file in modern standards (2013)?

Tags: php, mysql, security

There is a LOT of information out there and I am trying to factor in all of this into a single page web app in php. Not trying to get into a debate, simply looking for a standard in modern sites, or if differences of opinion, just some risks this and other options entail.

Also I have my database connection in a connect.php file, in domain root and thinking of moving back a level as well.

```
<?php require_once "../../folder/config.php";
session_start();
ob_start();
$access = 'my_value'; 
// ...
if($connectDatabase == TRUE) {
  $action=TRUE;
  include('connect.php');
}
```

Comment: Define 'hide'. If they have access to your raw PHP files on the server, I think you have bigger concerns than them finding your DB connection info... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

So long as all `*.php` files are served through the PHP interpreter then their contents [between `<?php` and `?>`] are as secure as your application is. The old style of naming includes like `dbinfo.inc` caused problems because `*.inc` file were simply served as text if you knew the extension. I prefer inc.dbinfo.php, class.mysql_db.php, view.news.php, etc for logical grouping in directory listings, but to each their own so long as they end in `.php`.

Once someone is able to perform code injection, or place/retrieve raw files onto/from your server it doesn't matter how many levels above the web root your database info is stored.

Comment: I did look at .inc and that is what got me looking into how secure my code really is. Good to know that solution is outdated. I will look more into php/mysql security, but I believe we are coded to the best of my knowledge for sql injection, not sure on all the other potential risks. It has always been my understanding that if these files are in the domain root or webserver is a higher risk.

Comment: Higher *potential* risk. It is possible that a script might output something that's normally captured by some output buffering statements, or generate more-descriptive-than-you-might-like error messages that might have been avoided or caught by the script that normally includes it. Once again, these can be *mitigated* by moving your includes directory outside of the web root, but it really boils down to how secure your code is.

Comment: One last question, if I have the php code optimized and includes moved, would use of .htaccess security features be beneficial; if so, what features?

Answer (score 0):

It should be secure but I would advise to disallow indexing on your site.  This will not allow people to go to that directory to see the php file, and if they try to go to the connect.php they will not see anything

http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/

Comment: I disagree with disabling indexing. Rationale: if you don't want to allow access to certain files, don't put them on your webserver in the first place.

Comment: Are you talking about <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">. I do have this, but if you are concerned about SEO, what would remedy the conflict?

Comment: I am not talking about indexing or crawling by search engines.  I am talking about the ability to see a "list" of files that are inside a directory if you don't have an index.php or index.html file page.  Therefore if you were to go to say, /images/ that generally contains images you will see an entire list.  This is also true with php files if indexing is allow

Answer (score -2):

Move the config file outside the public folder so it cannot be accessed via URL. Or, use a .htaccess files to protect the containing folder with

```
deny from all
```

or

```
<Files config.php>
    Order Deny
    Deny From All
</Files>
```